# C++ - assign Vector value to std::string without losing data

Tags: c++, string

I want to assign the value of a int vector to a std::string in order to pass it to another function, for now i wrote this code:

```
int input;
std::cout << "Insert the value to convert: \t";
std::cin >> input;
std::string output;

std::vector<int> rem;

int r; //Just a simple binary conversion
while(input != 0) {
    r = input % 2;
    rem.push_back(r);
    input /= 2;
}
std::reverse(rem.begin(), rem.end());
for(std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = rem.begin(); it != rem.end(); ++it) {
    output += *it; //Assign every value of the iterator to string variable

}
std::cout << output; Print the value of output
```

The problem with my code is that the string contains weird characters like `☺  ☺☺☺ ☺☺☺☺  ☺`...is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: Are you missing a `to_string` call?

Comment: Pass the output into something like `xxd`, or redirect it into a file and use an editor that lets you see the binary data. Compare this to an output like "10011101111001".

Comment: `std::bitset<sizeof(int)*8>(input).to_string()`

Comment: `output += *it` needs to be `output += static_cast<char>(*it) + '0'`

Comment: There’s a big difference between digits, which are characters, and numbers.

Comment: use a `std::ostringstream` instead

Comment: @scohe001 your solution works, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why you are not converting int to string while adding to output?
Try this:

```
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << *it;

    std::string str = ss.str();
    output += str; //Assign every value of the iterator to string variable
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need an additional copy of your data for what you are trying to achieve:

```
std::string output;
while(input) {
    output += (input % 2 ? "1" : "0");
    input /= 2;
}

std::reverse(std::begin(output), std::end(output));

std::cout << output;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to assign the value of a int vector to a std::string in order
>   to pass it to another function, for now i wrote this code:

Your problem is that an integer is implicitly convertible to char. The code `output += *it;` effectively implies something similar to:

```
char& i = *it;
i = 1; //Compiles, but how is 1 represented (1 != '1')
 //considering encoding etc?
```

I've taken a stab at it with functional approach. You can just replace std::cout in the end with a std::ostringstream instance and get its string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Insert the value to convert: \t";
    std::vector<int> rem;
    // Get user input...
    std::copy_if(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<int>(),
        std::back_inserter(rem), [](int val) {return val != 0;});
    //Do your transforation
    std::transform(rem.begin(), rem.end(), rem.begin(), [](int i){return i % 2; });
    //And reverse and copy to stream...     
    std::reverse(rem.begin(), rem.end());
    std::copy(rem.begin(), rem.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

NOTE:
I agree with both other answers, but also feel this answer highlights the issue.